# Visual Studio 2019 blurry on remote server over remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have a vm (Hyper-V) running Windows Server 2016, and on that instance I am running Visual Studio 2019 Pro. Everything in VS is a little bit blurry: the text editor, menus, solution explorer, everything.

Nothing else inside the vm instance is blurry: desktop perfect, Chrome browser/pages perfect, windows explorer perfect.

There is no Compatibility tab available on the devenv.exe for VS2019. I went down a rabbit hole trying to solve that, and eventually found a way via right-click, Troubleshoot Compatibility...and eventually that sort of worked, but it made all VS display in super tiny fonts, almost unreadable, but not blurry anymore. This was worse, so I put it back.

I have another vm that runs Win10 Pro instead of Windows Server 2016, and my VS2019 Pro on that instance is perfect, not blurry at all.

How can I solve this blurriness problem?

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain, I had the same issue and thought my eyesight was failing me.  It sounds like you need to enable the new VS2019 DPI awareness feature.
[image]

But if that doesn't work, then perhaps it's time to see the optometrist ;)

Also whilst you're at it, I'd recommend setting these (somewhat related) parameters to make VS2019 a little snappier in the rendering department, e.g. scrolling the editor.
[image]

Comment: This seems promising, but that setting is grayed out for me. And there is no `Compatibility` tab on my devenv.exe, which I read elsewhere is the key to solve this. So I am stuck.

Comment: I don't have the compatibility tab either, but it really shouldn't matter as VS2019 was made natively dpi aware a few years ago.  Check out the SO post on the greyed out option.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610636/visual-studio-2019-option-optimize-rendering-for-screens-with-different-pixel

Comment: This worked for me when remoting to my Azure Virtual Desktop.  Thanks!